# How set GMail as default mail client on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, gmail, windows-registry, email-client, regedit

How set GMail as default mail client on Windows XP?
I would prefer a solution that allow me to use Google Chrome to launch GMail.

Answer (score 1):

Try [affixa](http://www.affixa.com/), it does exactly what you need.

> Many applications have the built-in capability to send emails. For example, you can send a document from Microsoft Word, a PDF from Adobe Acrobat, or photos from Windows Explorer. The problem is that these don’t work with web-based email.
>
> Affixa allows you to easily attach files to new messages in Gmail, Google Apps, Zimbra, Office 365, Outlook Web App and Yahoo! Mail.
>
> Oh, and it handles “mailto”s too, so when you click on an email address, you can choose which mail account to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GmailByDefault XP](http://www.zedlan.com), it works on Windows XP and all versions of web browsers among others Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Google Gmail notifier:
http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9429

Comment: This is a simple approach

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2202/gmail_default_email_program_xp_vista_os_x/
http://lifehacker.com/129818/ask-lifehacker--gmail-as-default-mail-program

Answer (score 0):

The best I've found (and I've looked at a lot of these) is [Scott's Gmail Alert](http://ga.graphicport.net/).